# How to working with css framework in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, frameworks, materialize

I tryed to use css frameworks lots of times. But i cant found any guide what to do. Just some post from other developers. Can you help me with the guide, how to import and use css framework in my expressjs project.

For instance, i started new project with [express generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html):

`express --view=pug --css=sass`

next, i installed [materialize](http://materializecss.com/about.html)

`npm install materialize-css`

What i must to do next??? How to connect `js` and `sass` files with my project? How to compile all, if i tryed to do just a website? Where i can find good guides about such things, if i will have more questions?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**npm** was originally to get Node Module, but with the essort of the Javascript language (and the advent of browserify, webpack,etc), it has a bit grown up.

In fact, you can even **download Bootstrap on npm**, that is not a server side framework. **Browserify** permits you to use AMD/RequireJS/CommonJS on client side so node modules can be used on client side. Same goes for **Webpack** module bundler.

If you `npm install bootstrap` (if you don't use grunt or gulp file to move to a dist folder), your bootstrap will be located in some location like below.

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
```

You need to include this in your **.html** file.

For **sass** if you use **grunt** then you will be using this plugin [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) to convert sass to css and add the destination file to the **.html** file. Similarly goes for **gulp**.